# Grid adaptiveness in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am using a grid with 3 columns on a large screen, 2 on a medium and 1 on a small screen. I want the grid to use all the space in the columns. The grid contains 6 VBox's with a number of buttons. Sadly, they don't align like I have in mind. The second row columns should start right after the end of the columns of the first row.

### Right now, it looks something like this:

[image: Current]

### I would love it to look like this

[image: goal]

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is masonry layout. I create a custom control similar using the masonry layout. I used to display products of different sizes in a grid like container.

Attaching the screenshot link below : https://github.com/bhardwaj-rahul/sapui5-masonryLayout/blob/master/Example.gif

---

Update:

The Grid structure is obtained by creating multi-column layout.

To create multi column layout, we use the CSS property : column-count.

```
.masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
```

And to achieve the dynamic layout, i.e, more columns on large screen and less columns on small screen, we make use of @media rule.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}
```

Also, we do not specify the fixed height for each item, it keeps inserting one item after another. I've added custom CSS to make it look like a card which you can edit as per your requirements.

[image]

and the github link to the project  : https://github.com/bhardwaj-rahul/sapui5-masonryLayout